# Have regex ignore new lines and just match on a whole large string?

Tags: java, regex

I have this string here:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index555 ON
SOME_TABLE
(
    SOME_PK          ASC
);
```

I want to match across the multiple lines and match the SQL statements (all of them, there will be many in 1 large string)... something like this, however I am only getting a match on `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index555 ON`

```
(CREATE\s.+;)
```

note: I am trying to accomplish this in java if it matters.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use DOTALL and MULTILINE flags when compiling a regular expression. Here is a Java code example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s =
        "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index555 ON\nSOME_TABLE\n(\n    SOME_PK          ASC\n);\nCREATE UNIQUE INDEX index666 ON\nOTHER_TABLE\n(\n    OTHER_PK          ASC\n);\n";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^;]*?('.*?')?)*?;\\s*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);

        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        while (m.find())
        {
        System.out.println ("--- Statement ---");
        System.out.println (m.group ());
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
--- Statement ---
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index555 ON
SOME_TABLE
(
    SOME_PK          ASC
);

--- Statement ---
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index666 ON
OTHER_TABLE
(
    OTHER_PK          ASC
);
```

Comment: you only need DOTALL

Answer (score 8):

Check [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> The regular expression . matches any character except a line terminator unless the DOTALL flag is specified

So you need to do something like this

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("your pattern", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Answer (score 5):

The `DOTALL` flag lets the `.` match newlines, but if you simply apply it to your existing regex, you'll end up matching everything from the first `CREATE` to the last `;` in one go.  If you want to match the statements individually, you'll need to do more.  One option is to use a non-greedy quantifier:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^CREATE\\b.+?;",
    Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

I also used the `MULTILINE` flag to let the `^` anchor match after newlines, and `CASE_INSENSITIVE` because SQL is--at least, every flavor I've heard of.  Note that all three flags have "inline" forms that you can use in the regex itself:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?smi)^CREATE\\b.+?;");
```

(The inline form of `DOTALL` is `s` for historical reasons; it was called "single-line" mode in Perl, where it originated.)  Another option is to use a negated character class:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?mi)^CREATE\\b[^;]+;");
```

`[^;]+` matches one or more of any character except `;`--that includes newlines, so the `s` flag isn't needed.

So far, I've assumed that every statement starts at the beginning of a line and ends with a semicolon, as in your example.  I don't think either of those things is required by the SQL standard, but I expect you'll know if you can count on them in this instance.  You might want to start matching at a word boundary instead of a line boundary:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\bCREATE\\b[^;]+;");
```

Finally, if you're thinking about doing anything more complicated with regexes and SQL, *don't*.  Parsing SQL with regexes is a fool's game--it's an even worse fit than HTML and regexes.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the various flags that can be passed to [Pattern.compile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). I think DOTALL is the one you need.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the [Pattern.DOTALL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.Flag.html#DOTALL) flag to match across lines.